# Ajax form data pass

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How can I pass the form data on my PHP file? I have tried the below solution but it was not worked for me. I need to pass all checkboxes on my PHP function.I have tried but not getting the perfect value that I need?

Please check the issue and guide me where I was wrong.

```
<form id="filterForm" method="post">

          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Beer Brands
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
              <ul>
                <li><input class="clickBox" type="checkbox" name="beer_brands[]" value="valu1" />Test</li>
                <li><input class="clickBox" type="checkbox" name="beer_brands[]" value="valu2"/>Test</li>
                <li><input class="clickBox" type="checkbox" name="beer_brands[]" value="value3"/>Test</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Locations
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
              <ul>
                <li><input class="clickBox" type="checkbox" name="locations[]" value="value4" />Test</li>
                <li><input class="clickBox" type="checkbox" name="locations[]" value="value5"/>Test</li>
                <li><input class="clickBox" type="checkbox" name="locations[]" value="value6"/>Test</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Sort By
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
              <ul>
                <li><input class="clickBox" type="checkbox" name="sort_by[]" value="value7" />Test</li>
                <li><input class="clickBox" type="checkbox" name="sort_by[]" value="value8"/>Test</li>
                <li><input class="clickBox" type="checkbox" name="sort_by[]" value="value9"/>Test</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>

        </form>
```

JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  jQuery(".clickBox").click(function(e){ 

      var b_b_Array  = []
      var location_Array  = []
      var sort_by_Array  = []

      jQuery('.clickBox').each(function ()
      {
          //debugger;
          jQuery("input[name='beer_brands[]']").each( function () {
              if(jQuery('input[name="beer_brands[]"]').is(':checked')) {
                b_b_Array.push(jQuery(this).val());
              }
          });

          jQuery("input[name='locations[]']").each( function () {
              if(jQuery('input[name="locations[]"]').is(':checked')) {

                location_Array.push(jQuery(this).val());
              }
          });

          jQuery("input[name='sort_by[]']").each( function () {
              if(jQuery('input[name="sort_by[]"]').is(':checked')) {

                sort_by_Array.push(jQuery(this).val());
              }
          });

      });

      console.log(b_b_Array);
      console.log(location_Array);
      console.log(sort_by_Array);

      var ajaxurl = "<?php bloginfo('url');?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php";

      jQuery.ajax({
          url: ajaxurl,
          type : 'post',
          data: {
            'action':'all_give_aways_filter',
            'data' : jQuery("filterForm").serialize(),
          },
          success : function( response ) {
              console.log(response);
              // jQuery("div#errMsg").css({'background-color':'white','color':'red'});
              // jQuery("div#errMsg").html(response);
          }
      });

  });

});

</script>
```

Please Help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try replace this JavaScript. Hope this help you

```
function get_checkbox_value(){
    var array = [];
    jQuery(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i, _this){
      var checkboxname = jQuery(_this).attr('name'); checkboxname = checkboxname.replace('[]','');
      array[checkboxname]=[];
      array[checkboxname].push(jQuery(this).val());
    });    
    return array;
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery("#filterForm").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var formdata = get_checkbox_value();
        var ajaxurl = "<?php bloginfo('url');?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php";

      jQuery.ajax({
          url: ajaxurl,
          type : 'POST',
          data: {
            'action':'all_give_aways_filter',
            'data' : formdata,
          },
          success : function( response ) {
              console.log(response);
          }
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: There is no need for `jQuery("#filterForm").submit` at all since the form is never submited in the first place. Submit form event will never happen here, so this also won't work.

Comment: Ok also replace your code its working 'jQuery(".clickBox").click(function(e){'

Comment: Why are you ajax submit code inserted inside of the click event?

Comment: It is not my code. it is OP's code. And there is nothing wrong with inserting AJAX inside a click event, it's perfectly valid to do so.

Comment: @vadivela I did a minor change in your function and working fine for me.Thanks.

function get_checkbox_value(){
    var objValue = {};
    jQuery(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i, _this){
      // var array = [];

      var checkboxname = jQuery(_this).attr('name'); 
      checkboxname = checkboxname.replace('[]','');
      if(!objValue[checkboxname])
      {
        objValue[checkboxname]=[];
      }
      objValue[checkboxname].push(jQuery(_this).val());
    
    });
    return objValue;
}